# MySQL create function won't return sets

Tags: mysql

I can't get this work with MySQL 5.x. This function should return all relevent rows from the select-statement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getuids(root INT)
RETURNS SET OF INT AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN SELECT uid FROM pages WHERE deleted = 0
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL';
```

Any idea what I made wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A MySQL function may not return a row or set of rows in MySQL. Only a stored procedure can return rows. This is true up to and including MySQL 5.4. See the [Limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) page. Usage of stored procedures as tables or where clause values in queries is also unavailable.

About the best you can do if you need to use a function is to use GROUP_CONCAT to get the values into a comma-separated list:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getuids() RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
BEGIN
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uid SEPARATOR ',') INTO @uid_list FROM pages WHERE deleted = 0;
RETURN @uid_list;
END
```

Then in your select statement that needs to check the uids, you can use the FIND_IN_SET function like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(my_field, get_uids());
```

P.S. I had originally posted links to the GROUP_CONCAT and FIND_IN_SET functions on the MySQL website, but Stack Overflow would only let me use one link. Yay for being new.