# How to use stored function in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I have an stored function in MySQL `get_parents_by_id()`

but when I try to use it in WHERE condition it generates an error.

For example:

```
SELECT id, parents, level 
FROM categories
WHERE parents IN get_parents_by_id(@id);
```

It doesn't work correctly, and the sample with:

```
WHERE parents IN (SELECT get_parents_by_id(@id));
```

doesn't work as well.

Help me people, I can't find anything in book about MySQL...

Comment: what does @id contain?  What is the sql for get_parents_by_id?

Comment: It contains INT value

Comment: get_parents_by_id returns string like "(0,2,3,7)"

Comment: Please provide the error message as well.

Comment: 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get_cat_parents(@id)' at line 34 SQL1.sql 34 26

Comment: Does SELECT get_parents_by_id(@id)) work on its own? If so, what does it return: one row with a string? mulitple rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT id, parents, level 
FROM categories
WHERE find_in_set(parents, get_parents_by_id(@id));
```

Note: This would require get_parents_by_id() to return a comma delimited string (varchar).

Note2: Stored functions normally return individual values, not result sets.

according to format in comments:

```
WHERE find_in_set(parents, 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(get_parents_by_id(@id), ')', ''), '(', ''));
```

Comment: This should work if you can't change the procedure to return a set rather than a string, but will probably need a minor tweak to trim off the brackets at either end of the string.

Comment: @Kickstart What brackets?  Did `get_parents_by_id` get defined somewhere and I missed it?  As to sets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170304/mysql-create-function-wont-return-sets

Comment: The 3rd comment on the original post defines what it returns.

Comment: I have done it with FIND_IN_SET() function. ebyrob, Kickstart, oldmanprogrammer, nif - THANKS A LOT, YOU ARE THE BEST PEOPLE IN THE NET!!!

Answer (score 0):

It needs to return an array of ids, not a string containing comma separated ids.

At the moment your query is doing:-

```
SELECT id, parents, level 
FROM categories
WHERE parents IN '(0, 2, 3, 7)';
```